# Custom Button that opens a visualforce popup, is needed to be reused as List Button as well

Tags: javascript, custom-button, related-list, list-button

I have a custom button on Account detail page that onclick javascript opens a visualforce page

```
window.open('/apex/test_k?id={!Account.Id}', '_blank', 
'height=600,width=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no');
```

I have 2 other objects Secondary_Stakeholder  & Primary_Stakeholder where ACcount is referenced. I need to add this button as a List button in the related list of these other 2 objects.

I want to reuse the detail page button code and send a list of accounts to the visualforce page instead of a single Account Id.

Visualforce Page code :

```
<apex:page id="thePage" standardController="Account" showHeader="false" extensions="test_k" sidebar="false">
<script >
function cw()
{
self.close();
}

function cw1()
{
alert("Account is added to the Account List  ");
self.close();
}

function selectNew(cmd)
{
alert(cmd);
if(cmd=='create')
{
createNew();

}
}

</script>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="createNew" action="{!f1}" reRender="nonepopup" />
        <apex:selectList value="{!s}"  multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="selectNew(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Matrix}"/>
        </apex:selectlist>
    <apex:commandButton value="OK" action="{!addlineItem}" oncomplete="cw()"/>

  <apex:outputPanel id="nonepopup">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!popup}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!popup}" style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;" >
               Name of the new List : <br/>
               <apex:inputText id="theInputText" value="{!s1}"/><br/><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Create" action="{!createandclose}" oncomplete="cw1()" rerender="nonepopup"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
<style type="text/css">
        .custPopup{
            background-color: #e1f1f7;
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;

        }
        .popupBackground{
            background-color:black;
            opacity: 0.10;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }

</style> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller code :

```
public class test_k {
public Id Acc_Id {get;set;}
public Boolean nonepopup{get;set;}
public Boolean popup{get;set;}
Public Map<Account_List_Item_vod__C,Account_list_vod__C> accmap = New Map<Account_List_Item_vod__C,Account_list_vod__C>();
Public List<Account_List_Item_vod__C> itemmap = new List<Account_List_Item_vod__C>();
Public string s{get;set;}
Public string s1{get;set;}

  public test_k(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  Acc_Id =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
  }
  public List<SelectOption> getMatrix() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    list<Account_List_vod__c> pv= [select name,id from Account_List_vod__c];
    for (Account_List_vod__c p:pv) {
      options.add(new SelectOption(p.id,p.name));
    }
    options.add(new SelectOption('create','<Create New List>'));
    return options;
  }

public void addlineItem() {
  Account_List_Item_vod__c item = new Account_List_Item_vod__c(Account_vod__c=Acc_Id,Account_List_vod__c=s);
  Insert item;
}

public void createandclose() {
accmap.put(new Account_List_Item_vod__c(Account_vod__c=Acc_Id),new Account_List_vod__c (Name=s1));
insert accmap.values();
for (Account_List_Item_vod__c key : accmap.keySet()) {

    Account_List_Item_vod__c o = key;
    o.Account_List_vod__c =accmap.get(key).Id;
    itemmap.add(o);

} 
insert itemmap;
popup = false;    
    } 
    public void closeNone() {        
        popup = false;    
    } 

public void f1() {        
        popup = true;    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Create new  buttons and select button type as List Button, use the same VF page to override. you need to add standardcontroller with the recordSetVar attribute defined on your page